# How to create a Depth non compresed Video Using in Linux

Tags: linux, video, recording

I get the video from a depth camera, I have the disparity and also the Depth. Now I would like to save a non compressed video. I tried OpenCV but it seem that is not working in linux( I was not able to open the video writer with different formats) and also it compress the video.

Is a 640x480  8-bits(disparity) or 16-bits(depth) image.

Does anyone know a library or a way to save a video in linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Video4Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux)